# How to get steamcommunity market item lowest price using Javascript and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, steam, cross-domain-policy

I'm coding from time to time and make scripts for fun and to help others.  How can I get JSON from other site? As we know, there are cross-domain restrictions.. This is what I'm trying to get: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20M4A1-S%20|%20Hyper%20Beast%20(Minimal%20Wear). I have tried this:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=3&market_hash_name=StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20M4A1-S%20|%20Hyper%20Beast%20(Minimal%20Wear)',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you have any errors or output?

Comment: Uh, i forgot to mention. I get a GET error with link in script. When i open link from script, I get blank array "[]", i should get "{"success":true,"lowest_price":"65,90\u20ac","volume":"17","median_price":"72,--\u20ac"}"

Comment: Try to delete this: `https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=` and use just URL

Comment: Then I get error due to cross-domain-policy